# Browser sets cookie to have lower max-age than desired

Tags: javascript, cookies

I use the following JavaScript to set a cookie:

```js
document.cookie = 'theme=dark; path=/; max-age=31536000; samesite=strict';
```

The expire time is `60 * 60 * 24 * 365 = 31536000`, which is 1 year represented in seconds.

However, when the JavaScript runs and I inspect the cookie in the browser, I see:

```
Created: Monday, August 2, 2021 at 7:57:15 AM
Expires: Saturday, January 29, 2022 at 6:57:15 AM
```

That's a difference of `15552000000` milliseconds, or 180 days. Why isn't it 365 days, as expected?

My browser is Brave, Version 1.27.109 Chromium: 92.0.4515.115 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Brave seems to set a max-age allowable to be 6 months, if you try and extend beyond that the browser will auto set the expires date to 6 months max.  Have you checked the cookie in other browsers and what are the expires on those?

Comment: see here for brave deviation on this - https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/wiki/Deviations-from-Chromium-(features-we-disable-or-remove)#modified-features-and-functionality

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
document.cookie="cookiename=cookievalue; expires= 02 Oct 2022 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try it. URL: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp